# Iniciar sesión en facebook y google con PHP

Tags: php, login, facebook, sesiones

Estoy realizando un login con Facebook y google en php, para ello estoy haciendo uso de la librería `hybridauth`. Realicé un proyecto de prueba y ahí funcionó bien, pero al momento se pone una ventana en blanco. con la url `?login=Google`  o `login=Facebook`

Este es el código para la configuración de las keys:

```
<?php
return

        array(
            "base_url" => "http://localhost/sesionRedes2/hybridauth.php",
            "providers" => array(
                "Facebook" => array(
                    "enabled" => TRUE,
                    "keys" => array(
                        "id" => "---",
                        "secret" => "---"
                    ),
                    "scope" => "email"
                ),
                "Google" => array(
                    "enabled" => TRUE,
                    "keys" => array(
                        "id" => "---",
                        "secret" => "---"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
?>
```

Código donde llamo los enlaces:

```
<?php

                Auth::getUserAuth();?>

               <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="?login=Facebook" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>Facebook</a>
                    <a href="?login=Google" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google"><span class="fa fa-google"></span>Google</a>
                </div>
```

Comment: y que te sale en la consola de comandos??? verificaste que las urls son ?login=Facebook

Comment: @FranciscoNuñez como valido lo de la consola de comandos y si las urls son esas y están correctas

Comment: Primero debes abrir la consola de comando, si existe algún error hay saldrá. Y podrás verificar que la URL que envías en ese formato es correcto...